# YouTube Iframe API - video will sometimes not play via custom controls and instead, it refreshes the video

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

A bit of a strange one - I'm working with the YouTube iFrame API for the first time, building a skin for a customers site.

I've followed the code examples provided by Google/YouTube (https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5#IFrame_Player_API).

The issue is that when clicking the play button, which calls player.playVideo(), under some circumstances it will play, but mostly, it just appears to refresh the video with no errors logged in the console. The video will fade to black as if it was about to play, but instead it fades back to the video "poster" with the play button.

You can view the entire code here - https://codepen.io/james-morton/pen/BEZGvm

I've tried various different things such as instead of using:

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
```

.. I tried this as per other examples to no avail

```
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
```

Again, to be clear, the controls sometimes works, and sometimes it doesnt - same machine, same browser, same video - I've tried other videos and the same result. It's really inconsistent as it sometimes works.

Any ideas?

Edit:

After further debugging using the below:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event){
  console.log('State Change: ' + event.data);
}
```

I can see that for when it doesn't load, the player's state has changed from -1 (Unstarted) to 3 (Buffering), and then back to -1 (Unstarted) when clicking the play button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the issue appears to be with CodePen - having transferred all of the code to my own environment, it works flawlessly with no playback issues via the controls.

Having reviewed https://css-tricks.com/play-button-youtube-and-vimeo-api/ that use a very similar setup, the problem was easily replicated on CodePen, and comments (all the way back from 2014) describe the issues that I experienced.

Hopefully this will be useful to others that spot this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange one! I didn't quite 'solve' it but I have some feedback. On running your code, at first I couldn't get it to play at all (by either the middle 'YT' play button or by the custom play button), but when I used your 'ff' button (when it hadn't yet started to play), there was obvious signs that it had being activated. I changed the `z-index` in the `yt-player` from 2 to -2 and then was able to use the middle button to start play. After the initial play, I had no problem using the custom buttoms (pause/play worked fine) - and I refreshed and tried it multiple times, each time with success.

The one big issue is starting the first video play with the custom play button. You could maybe autostart it (perhaps with a delay?) to circumvent having to use the middle button? I did inspect the widths of the buttons (to see if maybe padding / overlap) may be affecting the play button but didn't find anything. I did notice that when I played the video that it was rising slightly from it's initial position so I tweaked the css a tiny bit (only a very slight tweak). Here's my [codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rbrbbM) (It's not that different from yours..) I hope this helps .. if even a bit.

Comment: I only saw your comment about the load/buffering now.. hmmm! Maybe too long a response time? ..too big a video? Have you tried it with a v short video? It is quite a long vid

Comment: Thank's for looking into this - so the middle play button will eventually have a custom one overlaid (which then disappears once the video is playing) - the z-index is so that the video appears "behind" the TV frame as it has wavy borders which wouldn't look too great if the YT video was on top. I did suggest to the client to go for a self hosted video (as they are much easier to work with), but they insist on YouTube.

Comment: @JMD yes I understood that that's why you adjusted the z-index, but I readjusted it just so I could get it to play, and discovered that the rest of the buttons work fine, it's really just the play button that has the issue. Clients... tch.. can be a pain in the bum! ;)

Comment: @JMD btw, the reason for the value of the max-height is 534 -5% of that value (26.7 rounded to 27) , so 534-27 =507 .. just in case you were wondering  (I didn't pluck it out of thin air! lol). Also it's better practice (in my opinion) to use double quotes in getting elements by Id - that's why I subbed the single quotes for double quotes.